# Bash scripting not working on git actions workflows

Tags: github, github-actions

Below code in one of my workflow is not working under the "run" section

```
UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME=myear
  
  echo $?
  if [[ "envName" == "envName" ]] 
  then
    UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME=updatedName.ear
  fi
  echo $?
  
  echo ear name : $UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME
```

It is always printing `echo ear name : myear`. I have tried online compilers and it is working perfectly but not in my git actions workflow

Comment: I have tried single [ ,=, '' . But nothing is working

Comment: Are you sure it's running Bash, not `sh`?

Comment: What exactly does your actual YAML look like? Or is this a script in a file? Then how are you running that from the YAML definition?

Comment: This is a script in the yaml file in the 'run'

The run step is
'run: |
          echo "Deploying"
                 
          PATH=/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/bin:$PATH
          
          UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME=$EARFILE
          
          echo $?
          if [[ "envName" == "envName" ]] 
          then
            UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME=updatedName.ear
          fi
          echo $?
          
          echo ear name : $UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME

          mv myapp.ear $UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME
| `

Comment: Please update the question to contain a reproducible example (YAML) that someone could copy to reproduce your problem.

Comment: try dropping double square braces and just have single square brace and try using 

if [ "envName" == "envName" ];  then
    UPDATED_EARFILE_NAME=updatedName.ear
  fi